# how to remove device udid from provisioning profile, i edit and remove them but they can install the new ipa

Tags: ios

I've developed an app and want to use it in some confirmed devices. But now I want some of the devices can not use this App any more. So I removed some devices' udid in the provisioning profile and compiled and signed again, but those removed devices still able to install the new ipa file which I compiled from the new provisioning profile.

I couldn't find any clue for this.

And then I removed the appid, create a new one and then create a new provisioning profile also, but still new ipa can be installed in those removed devices!

Your suggestion is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing devices from developer.apple.com account then you need to regenerate provisioning by selecting devices , then it will work

Comment: yes, now it work, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing devices from developer.apple.com account then you need to regenerate provisioning by selecting devices , then it will work